# pandas melt dataframe according to time index

Tags: pandas, melt

I have the following dataframe that I try to 'melt'.

[image]

So my aim is to get a output with 2 column

- Column name
- Value

So my output should look like [that's only the head of the output, I don't show it fully to be concise]

[image]

I have tried the following but it not works.

```
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=df.index, var_name="Name", value_name="Value")
```

It says: 
KeyError: "The following 'id_vars' are not present in the DataFrame:

PS: The columns are 'predictors' so **if not too complicated** I would be happy to add a P as prexix in the column name like P0 P1 P2 P3 P4 P5

[image]

Comment: pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars='index', var_name="Name", value_name="Value")

Comment: Perfect, I was not aware of the reset_index. Can you put it as answer?

Comment: Sure ~ done :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can just adding the `reset_index`

```
pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars='index', var_name="Name", value_name="Value")
```

Or using `stack`

```
df.stack().reset_index()
```

Comment: Note that if your index happens to have a name, you'll have to use that instead of `'index'`.

Comment: Why does `reset_index()` fix this? As I learn more about pandas, I feel more and more like it's all just a bunch of random hacks you have to learn about without any underlying structure you could actually learn and understand.